Maximum of Gaussians error check: Expectation of maximum of folded-normally distributed random variables
I am trying to show that if $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ are i.i.d, then $\mathbb{E}[\max(|Z_1|, |Z_2|, \ldots, |Z_n|)]\leq \sigma\sqrt{2\log (2n)}$. I tried to use the tail bound:
$$\mathbb{E}[\max(|Z_1|, |Z_2|, \ldots, |Z_n|)]=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\max(|Z_1|, |Z_2|, \ldots, |Z_n|)>t)dt$$
However, we see that
$$\mathbb{P}(\max(|Z_1|, |Z_2|, \ldots, |Z_n|)>t) = \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{|Z_i|>t \}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(|Z_i|>t)\leq 2ne^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}$$
so
$$\mathbb{E}[\max(|Z_1|, |Z_2|, \ldots, |Z_n|)]\leq 2n\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}dt = 2n\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$$
which is of course, not the bound I want. Is there any way I can change some of these steps differently to get the bound I want?
(Edit: I already looked at this question Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables, but the top answer suggested you could also approach this by a union bound and tail bound approach rather than the very nonintuitive exponential approach, so that was what I was trying to emulate.)

Does this answer your question? Expectation of the maximum of gaussian random variables

Well the first answer said another way one can do it is by combining a tail bound for Gaussians with a Union Bound, which was what I was trying to emulate, so no, unfortunately.

You could look at the complementary event to have an intersection ?

Given that $Z_1,\ldots, Z_n\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ are i.i.d,
$$\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}[\max(|Z_1|, \ldots, |Z_n|)]\leq \sigma\sqrt{2\log (2n)}.} \tag{1} $$
Note that
$$\max(|Z_1|, \ldots, |Z_n|) = \max(Z_1,  \ldots, Z_{n},-Z_1, \ldots, -Z_{n}). \tag{2}$$
We can show that for $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, which can be dependent, the following holds:
$$\color{blue}{\mathbb{E}[\max(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)]\leq \sigma\sqrt{2\log (m)}} \tag{3}.$$
Then, (1) follows from (3) using (2).

To prove (3), by Jensen inequality, for any non-zero $t \in \mathbb R$, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[\max(Y_1,  \ldots, Y_m)]=\\ \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}\big[\log \exp(t\max(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)\big] \\ \le \frac{1}{t} \log \mathbb{E}\big[ \exp(t\max(Y_1,  \ldots, Y_m)\big] \tag{4}.$$
Moreover,
$$\mathbb{E}\big[ \exp(t\max(Y_1,  \ldots, Y_m)\big]=\\ \mathbb{E}\big[ \max(\exp(tY_1),  \ldots, \exp(tY_m))\big] \\ \le \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}[ \exp(tY_i)]=m e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}. $$
From (4), this gives the following bound:
$$\mathbb{E}[\max(Y_1,  \ldots, Y_m)] \le \frac{1}{t} \log \left ( m e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2} \right ),$$
which is minimized for $$t=\sqrt{\frac{2\log m}{\sigma^2}},$$
establishing the bound in (3).
